# Save in localstorage and db and show it later

Tags: javascript, html, database, local-storage, innerhtml

I use Elementor Pro.
I have a button that is limited to 7 clicks, when clicking number 7 is disabled, and this is saved in localstorage to display later.
My problem if the user login from different device, the count start againg in 0. and obviously the code don't work for my need, The user after 7 click Never can click again.

How can resolve this?

this is the code:

```
<script>
 // On page load (or in whatever event creates the button)
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
 // Read the saved state from local storage (if not yet saved, will be null)
 let clickcount3 = localStorage.getItem("localStorage.clickcount3");

 if(localStorage.clickcount3>6)
     document.getElementById("showResultMasPack").style.visibility = "visible";

});
 
function CounterMastPack() {
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
 if (localStorage.clickcount3) {
   localStorage.clickcount3 = Number(localStorage.clickcount3)+1;
 } else {
   localStorage.clickcount3 = 1;
 }
 document.getElementById("resultMastPack").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount3 + " Click(s).";
} else {
 document.getElementById("resultMastPack").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
}
if(localStorage.clickcount3>6)
document.getElementById("showResultMasPack").style.visibility = "visible";      
}
</script>
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this **PROBABLY** belongs on [WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), another site in the Stack Exchange network since you mentioned Elementor Pro and WordPress has it's own approach to persisting data in the database.

Comment: When I put that I use Elementor Pro, if it is because my page is in wordpress, I apologize to everyone because it is obvious that I did not know that I can not use this important medium to see wordpress things. Again an apology and I will leave my need for help to your decision. Thank you all